# Broadcasting message to client at scheduled time using SignalR

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, signalr

I want to broadcast message using SignalR from server to all clients at particular server time. This broadcast message should be automatic where all clients keep listening to server method and once we reach the scheduled time on server, server should broadcast the message.

But I don't find a way to this. I was successful by invoking from a client and broadcasting it to all clients but not automatically.

How this can be achieved.

Comment: can you invoke once every x seconds from client and see isTimeToBroadCast?

Comment: Not sure that you want to use SignalR to do this. Actually it's pretty orthogonal to SignalR itself. Writing code that runs on an interval is really what you need to do. There's probably a .NET library you could use to schedule code to run at some time (though it'll never truly be realtime)

Answer (score 2):

First you need some sort of hub:

```
public class MyHub : Hub {}
```

You then can connect to this hub with clients or whatever you want to do.  Then you need some type of looping class that sends to your hub (you could also do this within the hub as a static timer but we'll do this as a separate class).

```
public class Looper
{
    public Timer Interval

    public Looper(TimeSpan interval)
    {
        Interval = new Timer(Loop, null, TimeSpan.Zero, interval);
    }

    private static void Loop(object state)
    {
        GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ChatHub>().Clients.All.executeYourMethod();
    }
}
```

Now we need to instantiate this class somewhere, we'll do that inside our hub as a static:

```
public class MyHub : Hub 
{
    public static Looper MyInterval = new Looper(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)); // Send every 1 second
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a timer to your hub class and broadcast to each client at the required intervals.